# Android sms : failed to back up sender name programatically

Tags: android, sqlite, sms, backup

I tried to back up messages of my devices. I backed up every thing like id, thread id, address, body, date, person etc. except sender name using Telephony.sms. i got null when I print person. However when i restore messages from my backup it shows "Anonymous" instead of sender name. How could I solve it? plz help. Here also a similar post but no answer.  [android sms sender name returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812438/android-sms-sender-name-returns-null)

I uses this code given below:

```
private void backupSMS() {
    Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
    Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri, null,
            null, null, null);
    // startManagingCursor(cursor1);
    // String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address",
    // "person", "date", "body", "type" };
    ArrayList<SMS> smsList = new ArrayList<SMS>();
    int _id = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms._ID);
    int thread_id = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID);
    int address = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS);
    int body = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.BODY);
    int date = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.DATE);
    int date_sent = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.DATE_SENT);
    int person = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.PERSON);
    int protocol = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.PROTOCOL);
    int read = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.READ); 
    int service_center = cursor1
            .getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.SERVICE_CENTER);
    int status = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.STATUS);
    int subject = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.SUBJECT);
    int type = cursor1.getColumnIndex(Telephony.Sms.TYPE);
    if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        String count = Integer.toString(cursor1.getCount());
        Log.d("Count", count);
        while (cursor1.moveToNext()) {
            SMS sms = new SMS();

            sms.setId(cursor1.getInt(_id));
            sms.setThread_id(cursor1.getInt(thread_id));
            sms.setAdress(cursor1.getString(address));
            sms.setBody(cursor1.getString(body));
            sms.setDate(cursor1.getLong(date));
            sms.setSDate(cursor1.getLong(date_sent));
            sms.setPerson(cursor1.getString(person));
            sms.setProtocol(cursor1.getInt(protocol));
            sms.setRead(cursor1.getInt(read));
            sms.setService_center(cursor1.getString(service_center));
            sms.setStatus(cursor1.getInt(status));
            sms.setSubject(cursor1.getString(subject));
            sms.setType(cursor1.getInt(type));
            smsList.add(sms);
        }
    }
    db = new SMSDatabase(this);
    if (db.addSMS(smsList)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                cursor1.getCount() + " SMS backedup succesfully",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Sms.PERSON` is an integer ID referencing an entry in your Contacts. It's not going to be the display name.

Comment: @Mike thanks for reply. but do u know which entity returns display name/ sender name?

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596908/wrong-reference-to-contacts-table-from-sms-inbox) for info on how to get the Contact from that ID. Please note, however, that your particular implementation may not use the `Sms.PERSON` column, in which case you'll have to get the Contact using the phone number.